# Extract the vendors with highest increase in total revenue from order table, divided by year/country/vendor - bigquery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, rank, partition

The original ORDERS table looks like this :

| order | country_name | date_local | vendor_name | gmv_local |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | Hse A | 559.6 |
| 02 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | Hse B | 573.5 |
| 03 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | Hse A | 559.6 |
| 04 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | Hse B | 573.5 |
| 01 | Singapore | 2012-10-02 | Hse H | 778.6 |
| 02 | Singapore | 2014-10-02 | Hse K | 120.6 |
| 03 | Singapore | 2012-10-02 | Hse H | 778.6 |
| 04 | Singapore | 2014-10-02 | Hse K | 120.6 |
| 01 | Bangkok | 2014-10-02 | Hse D | 563.6 |

I wanted to extract the top 2 vendors of each country with highest increase of `total_gmv` (a new column), `total_gmv` is created by `ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv`

I wanted to create a new column `diff_gmv`, where the total_gmv by country, by year and by vendor,

The resulting table should be something like this

| Year | country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv | 2012_total_gmv | diff_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | Singapore | HSE A | 2119.76 | 1119.76 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Singapore | HSE A | 1819.63 | 819.63 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | HSE C | 1019.6 | 119.6 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | HSE D | 819.6 | 119.6 | 700 |
| 2014 | Bangkok | Hse D | 1289.6 | null | 1289.6 |

Note that Bangkok does not have business in 2012 and thus only 1 vendor is shown

My current code (note that the original table has a LEFT JOIN, year is extracted from a timestamp)

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2014 THEN Ord.gmv_local ELSE 0 END)) - (SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2012 THEN Ord.gmv_local ELSE 0 END)) AS diff_gmv
FROM `Orders` AS Ord
LEFT JOIN `Vendors` AS vn
    ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    year
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ord.country_name ORDER BY (SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2014 THEN Ord.gmv_local END)) - (SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2012 THEN Ord.gmv_local END)) DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    year, Ord.country_name,
    total_gmv DESC;
```

My "diff_gmv" is not working and it is showing

| Year | country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv | diff_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | Singapore | HSE A | 2119.76 | -2119.76 |
| 2014 | Singapore | HSE A | 1819.63 | -1819.63 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | HSE C | 1019.6 | -1019.6 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | HSE D | 819.6 | -819.6 |
| 2014 | Bangkok | Hse D | 1289.6 | -1289.6 |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going...

```
with data as (
    #fill this in with your data/joined table
),
gmv_by_country_vendor_year as (
    select 
        extract(year from date_local) as year,
        country_name,
        vendor_name,
        sum(gmv_local) as total_gmv
    from data
    group by 1,2,3
),
gmv_by_country_vendor_2014 as (
    select * from gmv_by_country_vendor_year where year = 2014
),
gmv_by_country_vendor_2012 as (
    select * from gmv_by_country_vendor_year where year = 2012
),
joined as (
    select l.*, r.total_gmv as total_gmv_2012, ifnull(l.total_gmv,0) - ifnull(r.total_gmv,0) as diff_gmv
    from gmv_by_country_vendor_2014 l
    left join gmv_by_country_vendor_2012 r using(year,country_name,vendor_name)
),
ranked as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by year,country_name,vendor_name order by diff_gmv desc) as rn
    from joined
)
select * except(rn) from ranked
where rn <= 2
order by year, country_name, diff_gmv desc
```